# How call code jquery in controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need cal following code jquery in controler ruby on rail:

```
$('#voting_form').replaceWith('render 'polls/voting_form'');
```

**pole_votes controller**

```
    class PollVotesController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def create
        @poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:poll][:id])
        @poll_item = @poll.poll_items.find_by_id(params[:poll_item][:id])

        if @poll && @poll_item && !current_user.voted_for?(@poll)
          current_user.poll_votes.create({poll_item_id: @poll_item.id})

          render js: 'Ваш голос учтен.'
          #past my js code           

else
          render js: 'alert(\'Ваш голос не может быть учтен. Вы уже проголосовали\');'    
        end

      end
```

**_voting_form.html.haml**

```
= form_tag poll_votes_path, method: :post, remote: true, id: 'voting_form' do
  = hidden_field_tag 'poll[id]', @post.poll[:id]

  = render partial: 'posts/poll_item', collection: @post.poll.poll_items, as: :item  

  %p 
    %b 
      Итого голосов: 
      = "#{@post.poll.votes_count}"

  - if current_user.voted_for?(@post.poll)
    %p Вы уже голосовали!
  - else
    .btn-poll
      = submit_tag 'Голосовать', class: 'btn-bg'
```

How correct syntax for ruby on rails? and correct way for this?

**EDIT:**

I created file **poll_votes/create.js.erb** with code:

```
$('#voting_form').replaceWith("<%= render( 
            :partial => 'posts/voting_form', 
            :layout => false,                               
            :locals => { @post }).html_safe %>");
```

Without result. Display in terminal:

```
Started POST "/poll_votes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-07 14:14:29 +0300
Processing by PollVotesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XLXa9y1kE+RgDry20LxChoZ9iGA8XG5VroEcvRLQ0E0=", "poll"=>{"id"=>"46"}, "post"=>{"id"=>"25246"}, "poll_item"=>{"id"=>"85"}, "commit"=>"Голосовать"}
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 30453 LIMIT 1
  SQL (36.7ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_request_at` = '2015-08-07 11:14:29' WHERE `users`.`id` = 30453
USER: dborovsky2
  Poll Load (2.2ms)  SELECT `polls`.* FROM `polls` WHERE `polls`.`id` = 46 LIMIT 1
  PollItem Load (2.3ms)  SELECT `poll_items`.* FROM `poll_items` WHERE `poll_items`.`poll_id` = 46 AND `poll_items`.`id` = 85 LIMIT 1
  Post Load (2.5ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 25246 LIMIT 1
  PollItem Load (2.7ms)  SELECT `poll_items`.* FROM `poll_items` WHERE `poll_items`.`poll_id` = 46
   (2.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `poll_votes` WHERE (user_id=30453 AND poll_item_id IN (86,85))
   (2.0ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (2.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 30453 LIMIT 1
  PollItem Load (2.6ms)  SELECT `poll_items`.* FROM `poll_items` WHERE `poll_items`.`id` = 85 LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO `poll_votes` (`created_at`, `poll_item_id`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2015-08-07 11:14:29', 85, '2015-08-07 11:14:29', 30453)
  SQL (2.9ms)  UPDATE `poll_items` SET `poll_votes_count` = COALESCE(`poll_votes_count`, 0) + 1 WHERE `poll_items`.`id` = 85
   (48.0ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 136.5ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 112.0ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
```

What wrong?

Comment: What is the voting_form? Does it come before Create or after?

Comment: _voting_form come before create. I update my quastion. please check and help. Thank you

Comment: What happens when user submits voting form? Does a new Poll Vote gets created?

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit form using ajax.for this,your `_form.html.erb` must use `remote:true` to submit form using ajax.So this form when submitted goes to `create` method

```
 ##_form.html.erb(or any other view) 
 <%= form_for(@poll,:html=>{:remote=>true}) do |f |%>

 <%end%>

        ##your controller
        class PollVotesController < ApplicationController
          before_filter :authenticate_user!

        def create
            @poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:poll][:id])
            @poll_item = @poll.poll_items.find_by_id(params[:poll_item][:id])

            if @poll && @poll_item && !current_user.voted_for?(@poll)
              current_user.poll_votes.create({poll_item_id: @poll_item.id})
              ##render create.js.erb or you can use any other as well 
              render js
              #past my js code           

            else
              render js: 'alert(\'Ваш голос не может быть учтен. Вы уже проголосовали\');'    
            end

          end


##in create.js.erb
##assuming that polls/voting_form is present
$('#voting_form').replaceWith('render 'polls/voting_form'');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it

class PollVotesController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user!

```
    def create
        @poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:poll][:id])
        @poll_item = @poll.poll_items.find_by_id(params[:poll_item][:id])

        if @poll && @poll_item && !current_user.voted_for?(@poll)
          current_user.poll_votes.create({poll_item_id: @poll_item.id})

          render js     

         else
          render js: 'alert(\'Ваш голос не может быть учтен. Вы уже проголосовали\');'    
        end

      end
```

in `/app/views/poll_votes/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for  @poll, remote: true do |f |%>
```

Also check `jquery-ujs` and `jquery` is including into your layout properly otherwise `remote: true` will not work

and then in `/app/views/poll_votes/create.js.erb`

```
$('#voting_form').replaceWith('render 'polls/voting_form'');
```